# How to create a function with an unknown number of parameters?

Tags: c++

I need to create a function to calculate the average of int types. how to do it better?

Example:

```
   double calculate_average(int num1, ...) {
      .... 
      return sum / count;
   }

   int main() {
     calculate_average(5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
     calculate_average(3, 2); 
   }
```

Comment: The term is "variadic function". But you'd probably be better off just passing a container of values, such as a `std::vector`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template , see also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

Comment: *"how to do it better?"* pass a `std::vector<int> const&` for example, this will save many of the headaches that come with dealing with variadic templates.

Comment: @CoryKramer, vector doesn’t suit me, in my case

Comment: Could you elaborate why that is?

Comment: @CoryKramer, because we will know that the function already takes at least 1 argument - the vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) for this:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
double calculate_average(Ts... ts)
{
  return (((double)ts / sizeof...(ts)) + ... + 0);
}
```

Note the `sizeof...(ts)`, is a separate primitive for parameter packs. It's *not* a pack expansion, but instead gives the *number* of arguments that are passed into the function.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qaZdHf).

Comment: it's work! but how fix if call: calculate_average(2147483647, 1)

Comment: Try `calculate_average(2147483647l, 1);`. After all, the arguments you passed in are not `int`s anyway, so might as well pass in `long`s.

Comment: @cigien You could also fix your calculation with `return (((double)ts/sizeof...(ts)) + ...);`

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks. edited an option. This should convert all arguments to `double`s at least.

Comment: @NathanOliver but doesn't take care of overflow, so added that option, thanks

Comment: @cigien  `sizeof...(ts)`, could you explain that part? Is that another fold expression, a special case or what?

Comment: @cigien It's OK I've got it, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...

Comment: @john added anyway :) It is a special primitive, not a pack expansion.